# How to compare Two dates and show error alert in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns E and F which contain dates. When the user enters dates manually , I have to apply a validation that date in F cell should always be greater than date in corresponding E cell and if not than have to show error alert, have to add validation in L column

Comment: Could you please show us a sample of what you have written so far, including some sample data? I'm sure that many here could provide you with an answer even as the question is stated, but you need to show that you have done some effort in trying to find a solution before you came here asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want this error alert to look like? If you want it in the form of a message box, you'll need to use VBA for that.

However, there's a far simplier solution, by using conditional formatting.
Dates, in Excel, are simple numbers, so you can easily compare them, using simple `<` or `>` operators. You just create a conditional formatting, based on "greater than" or "lesser than" operation, as a formatting, you use cell filling (like red colour in case of wrong result).